# Creating view with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tried to create view type_of_the_house_view but it doesn't work. What could be the matter?

// the code is written on PostgreSQL

```
  create view real_property_and_seller_view
    as select (real_property.seller_id,
                     house_id,
                     cost,
                     floor,
                     square,
           surname,
           name,
           phone_number)
     from real_property left join seller
 on (real_property.seller_id = seller.seller_id);
```

Comment: `but it doesn't work` ... I can speculate about what looks wrong, but if you tell us the exact error message it would be helpful.

Comment: ERROR: column "row" has pseudo-type record

Answer (score 1):

You are over-using parentheses:

```
create view real_property_and_seller_view as
    select rp.seller_id, house_id, cost, floor, square,
           surname, name, phone_number
    from real_property rp left join
         seller s
         on rp.seller_id = s.seller_id;
```

You should also qualify *all* column names in the referenced in the query.  I might guess:

```
create view real_property_and_seller_view as
    select rp.seller_id, rp.house_id, rp.cost, rp.floor, rp.square,
           s.surname, s.name, s.phone_number
    from real_property rp left join
         seller s
         on rp.seller_id = s.seller_id;
```

The error is a little hard to explain.  When you use parentheses, the columns create a *tuple*, which is also called a *record* in Postgres.  This is not allowed for a view.